# Принцип и работа CSRF в Django

Tags: django

Люди добрые, объясните на пальцах, каким образом работает и как использовать самому CSRF?
Я думал, что подключил middleware, добавил {% csrf_token %} в каждую post-форму + подвесил context_instance=RequestContext(request) и все, но это счастье выдает 403 - CSRF verification failed. Уже голову сам себе задурил этой ерундистикой, объясните мне как нубу, что как и куда :)

Comment: Выложи код вьюхи, settings.py и кусочек шаблона.

Comment: Ответил в комменте к твоему ответу.

Comment: Разжеванный ответ с примером на новых версяих Django https://bovs.org/post/179/Zasita-ot-CSRF-v-Django-na-prostom-primere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы все правильно.
А попробуй включить не глобально, а оберни нужную вьюху в декоратор   `django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect`
Ну и протестируй.

Comment: Так я и декоратор тоже использовал... Короче какая-то магия с этим csrf!

Comment: В общем RequestContext + декоратор + {% csrf_token %} = все работает :) Только не понимаю, почему post-формы начали требовать csrf, ведь middleware отключен... Точно какая-то магия Django :D

Answer (score 1):

Иногда, когда надо просто сделать и думать особо не хочется, а тем более копаться, я делаю просто, как в документации. Конкретно у меня так, во вьюхе:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
```

Затем в самой вьюхе, перед тем как передается словарь в обработчик (у меня это делается через декоратор `@render_to('template.html')`, делаем так:

```
ctx = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b,
}
ctx.update(csrf(request))
return ctx
```

Тем самым дополняем наш словарь ctx, чем то, что нам не особо нужно знать. После этого в форму в шаблоне пишем:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    <fieldset>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="vaau" type="text" />
    ....
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Ну и если любопытно, то смотрим исходник, что за зверь это токой и что реально в html-коде страницы сгенерировалось.

Comment: В коде страницы генерируется скрытое поле со значением, которое загоняется из того, что какой-то магией добавилось в словарь :)) Получается как бы дополнительная проверка. В общем ничего интересного, на самом деле ;)
Использовали декоратор, он добавил в передаваемые параметры свои значения, и потом там где нам нужно - мы эти значения использовали, т.е. вставили {% csrf_token %}.